# Get buttons by tag from a dictionary c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, button

I have a list of buttons `List<Button> buttons` each contains a tag object.

Then a dictionary object

```
Dictionary<int, string> buttonGroups = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

How do I return a `List` of buttons from `List<Button> buttons` where their tags match the keys in `buttonGroups` using LINQ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
buttons.Where(b => buttonGroups.ContainsKey((int)b.Tag))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Button> matches = buttons.Where(b => buttonGroups.Keys.Any(k => k == b.Tag)).ToList();
```

or with a join (which might be slightly faster):

```
List<Button> matches =    
    (from b in buttons
    join g in buttonGroups.Keys
        on b.Tag == g
    select b)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
listButtons.Where (button => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(button.Tag) && buttonGroups.Containskey (int.Parse(button.Tag)).ToList()
```